# Name "X" does not exists in the namespace "clr-namespace:Y;assembly=Z"

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-4.0

I was recently designing a custom Window for WPF, my very first. But I had a problem with TargetType and clr-namespace.

The code is:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:sf="clr-namespace:Suite.Forms;assembly=bhsuite">
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="WButtonStyle">

</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="ButtonStyle">

</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type sf:BHWindow}" x:Key="BHWindowStyle">

</Style>
```

The problem is obviously at `BHWindowStyle`, where I try using sf:BHWindow

I tried:

- Adding `;assembly=MyAssembly`
- Including in project references:

  - **PresentationCore**
  - **PresentationFramework**
  - **WindowsBase**
  - **System.Xaml**
- Restarting as administrator
- Cleaning and rebuilding
- Change build platform from x86 to x64 to clean and rebuild.

Comment: Is this the only error? If not for that everything else would compile?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Yes dkozl. Glen: I see a warning and an error. The _error_ is 'Name "X" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace=Y;assembly=Z".', the _warning_ is 'Cannot find a public type named "X" by type reference. Row 4, position 71'. Note that for X I mean, in both cases (warning and error) the custom window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by removing `xmlns:sf="clr-namespace:Suite.Forms;assembly=bhsuite"`, compiling, re-writing that and then re-compiling the project.